# What does "matrix $A$ induces a linear operator on $\ell^2$" mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, terminology, infinite-matrices

In the description of Toeplitz matrices, it is said that:

> A bi-infinite Toeplitz matrix $A$ induces a linear operator on $l^2$.

I do not know what does it mean to a matrix induce an operator. And also, what is space is $l^2$? Thanks in advance. I hope this is not too trivial.

Comment: In this context, I think that $\ell^2$ refers to the set of infinite "sequences" $(x_j)_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}$ such that
$
\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} |x_j|^2 \text{ is finite.}
$

Answer (score 0):

Given your infinite matrix $\{a_{ij}\}_{i,j=1,2,\dots}$, given an element $x=(x_j)$ of $l_2$, the induced operator is defined by
$$
A(x)_i=\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}x_j
$$